# Can DBIx:Class optimize a COUNT(*) query and remove JOINs that are not used?

Tags: mysql, perl, dbix-class

Pagination calls a `->count` in `DBIx::Class` on a relationship that also has JOIN condition.

But the query itself does not use the JOIN condition, however, it is included in the query anyways.

This makes the `COUNT(*)` query slow.

Is there any way to instruct `DBIx::Class` to omit unused relationships from the final query?

The query looks like this:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM products me
LEFT JOIN models model ON model.id = me.product_model_id
WHERE (me.manufacturer_id = 123)
```

And I wish it could be reduced to:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM products me
WHERE (me.manufacturer_id = 123)
```

Comment: that join could affect the number of results if model IDs are not unique

Comment: Good point, in this case model IDs are PKs (unique).

Comment: Would it be unreasonable to just run that above query in DBI instead of DBIC?